# django import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(); still want to run debugger even if commented. WHY?

Tags: python, django, debugging, ipdb

Ihave problem with IPDB. I comment out it after I do not use it but after I run the web page after single refresh the debbuger is fired anyway. I have to referesh at least two times or so, to force django not willing going into debugging.

additionally I am expiriencing extremlly often `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

(if it matters I am running it in vagrant based vm)

Comment: I had similar issues when I was editing the code without finishing debugging properly (e.g. not sending 'c' or 'q' commands).

Comment: Check if there are some python processes still running which you wouldn't expect and check if killing them helps.

Comment: How are you running this; through a separate server (e.g. Apache), or with the built-in development server. If the former, you may need to restart the server as well.

Comment: @Evert I use normal development server of django run with `runserver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ensure I've killed the runserver/gunicorn and restarted it cleanly, to ensure there are no threads that are still running ipdb. (if you're using django-devserver, for instance, that's multi-threaded)

Comment: quite "brutforce" one, but probbably the most reliable ;-)

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely annoying!

Comment: I often end up exiting vagrant and reloading it. I don't know, to which extend it is conected with instability of vagrant+vmbox on Mac OS X.